# Agrupar JSON por valor de uma chave em python

Tags: python, json, data, dataframe

Sou iniciante em python e estou tentando resolver algo aparentemente simples, tentei o jmespath e o pandas, mas não consegui resolver.
Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
[
{
    "user":  "user1",
    "path":  "caminho1",
    "permission":  "read"
},
{
    "user":  "user1",
    "path":  "caminho2",
    "permission":  "full"
},
{
    "user":  "user2",
    "path":  "caminho1",
    "permission":  "write"
}
```

]

Eu preciso transforma-lo em um JSON igual abaixo:

```
[
{
    "user":  "user1",
    "path":  ["caminho1","caminho2"],
    "permission": ["Read","full"]
},

{
    "user":  "user2",
    "path":  ["caminho1"],
    "permission":  ["Read"]
},
```

]

Na verdade quero agrupar os dados pela chave "user" caso sejam repetidas.
Usando o código abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("data.json", encoding="utf-8") as meu_json:
    dados = json.load(meu_json)

    df = pd.DataFrame(dados)

print(df.groupby(['username'], as_index=False).sum()
            .to_json(indent=4, orient='records'))
```

Tenho a saida:

```
[
    {
        "username":"user1",       
        "path":"caminho1caminho2",
        "permission":"readfull"   
    },
    {
        "username":"user2",       
        "path":"caminho1",        
        "permission":"write"      
    }
]
```

As chaves path e permission ficam juntas.
Mas preciso deixar assim:

```
    "path":  ["caminho1","caminho2"],
    "permission": ["Read","full"]
```

Se alguém conseguir ajudar, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -2):

Pesquisando consegui resolver:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open(".\json\data.json", encoding="utf-8-sig") as meu_json:
    dados = json.load(meu_json)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dados)
    print(df.groupby(['user'],as_index=False).agg({'path': list, 'permission': list}).to_json(indent=4, orient='records'))
```

Saída desejada:

```
[{
        "username": "user1",
        "path": [
            "caminho1",
            "caminho",
            "caminho2"
        ],
        "permission": [
            "read",
            "write",
            "full"
        ]
    },
    {
        "username": "user2",
        "path": [
            "caminho1"
        ],
        "permission": [
            "write"
        ]
    }
]
```